# Save in MySQL database an image stored on Xampp localhost dierctory whithout form

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sorry, I am new coding html and php and at this point I don´t know how to progress. What I want to do is the next:

I am using a xampp server where I have a folder with images already stored on the server like this:

```
/img/ima1.png
/img/ima2.png
/img/ima3.png
```

I want to use PHP to save this images on a MySQL database as a blob without using html form, just use the path of the image to get the content and save it on my database, without a tmp file and forms.

please is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (column_name)
    VALUES(LOAD_FILE('/full/path/to/new/image.jpg');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql `LOAD_FILE` [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column_name`)
VALUES(LOAD_FILE('/full/path/to/new/image.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ImageDb(Image)
    VALUES("file_get_contents('/img/ima2.png')")";
```

try the above sql statement

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO ImageDb(Image)
    VALUES(".file_get_contents('/img/ima2.png').")";

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all image path from a folder using simple php script. Suppose folder name “images” . Use glob for this. This is php code

```
$dirname = "media/images/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach($path as $images) {
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column_name`)
VALUES(('$path'));
}
```